# Debugger encountered an exception but build was fine

Tags: c++, c, qt, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

On a Qt5 project on QtCreator, project build successfully but showed

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\atomic:935: error: Debugger encountered an exception: Exception at 0x7ff6f9963594, code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at: 0x50, flags=0x0 (first chance)

Click on it and editor goes to `atomic` located at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include
```

and stops at line

```
auto _As_bytes  = __iso_volatile_load32(_Mem);
```

```
    _NODISCARD _TVal load(const memory_order _Order) const noexcept { // load with given memory order
        const auto _Mem = _Atomic_address_as<int>(_Storage);
        auto _As_bytes  = __iso_volatile_load32(_Mem); // IT POINTS TO THIS LINE
        _Load_barrier(_Order);
        return reinterpret_cast<_TVal&>(_As_bytes);
    }
```

What is this telling me?

Full rebuild and is fine again. But rebuild again and again a few times and eventually that shows again.

What's going on? How to deal with this situation?

Any special tool that might be useful?

Comment: Since you're using atomic: are you sure the destructor of the atomic hasn't been invoked before this access? If the destruction happens concurrently you may have undefined behaviour in your program depending on the timing of the threads... On the other hand the address `0x50` indicates that you may be accessing a member of a class via a pointer that is null. If you encounter this issue, inspect the stack trace! Probably rebuilding does not actually fix this issue; you just may have gotten lucky on those runs of the the executable.

Comment: When it breaks into the debugger, open the stack frame window and find the frame that corresponds to your code.  Inspect the variables in that function.  `code: 0xc0000005` is access denied probably a rogue pointer.

Comment: @RichardCritten It's 'attempt to access an invalid address', in fact.  Which I guess is what you meant.

Comment: ***read access violation at: 0x50*** Looks like a possible null pointer.

Comment: @fabian I searched the project for `atomic` and got no results. Perhaps its used indirectly? Any suggestion on how to find who is using `atomic`? What atomic is used for?

Comment: Your debugger should treat this attempt to access the memory as a break point. Just repeatedly run the program until the error occurs and then inspect the stack trace. Link to the debug version of the qt libs, if you haven't done so already to be able to inspect the part of the stack that's in qt. This may be an issue with some signals occuring at a time when you don't expect them to do. Making sure to disconnect the slots could solve your issue in that case...

Comment: Look at the 'call stack' window in VS Debug>Windows>Call Stack. You can see what line in your code is calling that atomic code. Assuming you are running this under debug inside vs

Comment: What is `_Storage`? It appears to be the root of the pointer creation.

Comment: `_Atomic_address_as<int>(_Storage);`this is part of `atomic` code. So I don't know what's `_Storage`, right? Search returns nothing called `Storage` in my project

Comment: Your problem is likely in your code not your compilers code. Switch your "Stack Frame" to your code after the code breaks into the debugger and then look at the variables in your code.

Comment: @pm100 is it possible to do that on QtCreator?

Comment: Qt-Creator should have a debugger. Although I am a Qt developer on windows I don't often use Qt Creator. Instead I develop my Qt applications using Visual Studio Community and CMake to generate the VS Project. I have done that at work since 2008. With that said I am not telling you to change your IDE. There is a debugger in Qt-Creator it should have similar functionality.

Comment: @fabian In order to "Link to the debug version of the qt libs" should I just work in debug mode? Or, do I need to rebuild Qt itself in debug mode here? I installed it using online installer.

Comment: @drescherjm Off topic but what is better in VS? I'm on QtCreator for a few years and every time I have to open a project in VS my brain hurts. I heard debugging on VS is better, is it any different?

Comment: There are probably debug versions of the lib available via that online installer, assuming they aren't already installed. However you may not be able to step through the source code this way. If you can compile qt yourself, this would fix the issue without much additional effort, since you'll probably just leave the sources where they are. As for Qt Creator vs VS: Personally I never warmed up to Qt Creator and I certainly would miss the debugging/code browsing/auto completion functionality VS provides; I always had some problem with non VS IDEs in those regards.

Comment: I like the integrated tools that VS includes and the builtin debugging. With that said I can't really compare it to recent Qt-Creator because I really have not used Qt-Creator enough recently to be able to give a fair comparison.

Comment: I should give VS another try, I have a feeling I'm missing something. Last time I did it I miss easy h/cpp switch shortcut (and comment shortcut) and multiple tabs and open another window and it took longer than QtCreator to open. I often see VS people working in a single file at a time, while on QtCreator with multiple displays I have multiple portions of the codebase at an easy sight. Any blogs or so you'll recommend to get a  grasp about the latest cool VS tricks?