# Should I compile Qt VS use the online installer?

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, moc

I compiled Qt5 by myself years ago for a Linux project. These days I'm working on Windows and I install Qt5 using the online installer.

Here and there however I face indications that compiling Qt might led to a better debugging experience, last time I notice it was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394760/debugger-encountered-an-exception-but-build-was-fine?noredirect=1#comment127894051_72394760).

From that days I was using compiled Qt I don't have any memories of better experience than using the online installer.

So I would like to know more about the possible benefits of using a Qt compiled by myself. Is it worth it? Does it give me any extras compared to the online installer?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: You can use the online installer for initial development and works great with Qt Creator.  Maybe later, you might need to build it yourself.

Qt's Windows installer installs most everything you need - including pre-built reference binaries with the most common options available.  Perfect for initial development.  There's even an option to install the source with the binaries for easy debugging.  Download the symbols too if you do this.

You may want to compile the binaries yourself would be for any of the following reasons:

1. Build with your own custom patches
2. In case you need to change a build option like the renderer or openssl linkage.
3. You have a business requirement to build all code you ship.

At least those are the 3 reasons why we build Qt binaries directly ourselves on my team.

Comment: Or if Qt Company banned your IP and you just can't use the installer. Like it happened with Russian IPs.

Comment: If one insists, it would be possible to to get it through vpn, like they do in China. Anyway, I'm mostly wondering about debugging experience, which don't seem to be a reason according to the answer.

Comment: If I remember it correctly online installer is build with Microsoft compiler so if one needs Qt build with another compiler then one needs to build Qt. Why would one need that?